# Can the Java compiler do early binding for non-static methods?

Tags: java, late-binding, early-binding

Let's say that I have the following class:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("doing something.");
    }
}
```

Let's further assume, that all my project does is to call that `.something()` method. No overriding or any other funny-business going on.

```java
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
myObj.doSomething();
```

Does the `javac` compiler notice that this method call is not being overridden, and optimize the binding to "early binding"? I am asking out of curiosity; in any real-world application I would of course sprinkle `final`, `static`, and `private` all over my code.

Comment: The answer will of course depend on _which_ compiler you're using...  But there is no requirement for the compiler to do so in order to be considered a java compiler, and the one I have on my machine doesn't.

Comment: What happens if you use a `class loader` to load in a class at `runtime` that does extend `MyClass` and override `doSomething()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bytecode compiler (like `javac`) typically doesn't do early binding for instance method calls:

1. The Java model of separate compilation of classes means that this kind of optimization can only be applied when a class is calling one of its of methods.  (If `javac` hypothetically did early binding across classes, changing and recompiling one class could lead to the binding being incorrect.)
2. There is not a great deal of value, since the JIT compiler (or AOT compiler generator) is where most optimization is performed.

The JIT compiler in a modern JVM does extensive optimization based on the complete set of classes that have been loaded (so far).  This includes optimizing away method dispatching and inlining methods calls.  Furthermore, the JIT compiler is smart enough to keep track of key optimizations, and recompile when something like dynamic loading of a new class invalidates the previous optimizations.